# Is there a way to set environment variables for all profiles in launchSettings.json?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, environment-variables

I have multiple profiles in my launchSettings.json file that each set the same environment variable to the same value.

Example of current setup:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      ...
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",

        "COMMON_VARIABLE_ONE": "1",
        "COMMON_VARIABLE_TWO": "2"
      }
    },
    "ExampleProfile": {
      ...
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",

        "COMMON_VARIABLE_ONE": "1",
        "COMMON_VARIABLE_TWO": "2"
      }
}
```

Is there a way that these can be set such that I don't need to repeat setting the variable for each profile?

Comment: You just need to copy and paste it right?

Comment: @Anuraj Well yes. But we've had a number of issues from copy/pasted configuration values over time. Unfortunately copy/pasting is still prone to human error.